# How to hide the soap4r gem warnings

Tags: soap, soap4r

I write the ruby code to access the magento core api, with the help of soap4r gem. When i run the code it works perfectly, but the problem is it should giving the lots of soap warnings.

```
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/xsd/charset.rb:13: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:68: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:69: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/property.rb:70: warning: encoding option is ignored - u
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
/home/chandru/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/soap/rpc/element.rb:226: warning: Hash#index is deprecated; use Hash#key
```

i got the above the warnings.
So anyone tell me how to hide these kind of warnings.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

soap4r has a number of known issues with Ruby 1.9. You should consider using one of the newer SOAP toolkits, such as [savon](http://savonrb.com/) or [handsoap](https://github.com/unwire/handsoap)

Answer (score 0):

consider using soap4r-spox gem

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `$VERBOSE=nil` and all warnings disappear.